# Handling downloads in Java

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

How would I be able to handle downloads using HttpResponse in Java? I made an HttpGet request to a specific site - the site returns the file to be downloaded. How can I handle this download? InputStream doesn't seem to be able to handle it (or maybe I'm using it the wrong way.)

Comment: What API/library are you talking about? [Apache HttpComponents HttpClient v4](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/index.html)? If you don't know, please mention the package name of the `HttpResponse` and `HttpGet` classes you're talking about and preferably post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so that we can spot your mistake.

Comment: Indeed I am using the Apache HttpComponents. The answer you posted seems to be what I'm looking for. However, would it be possible to store all the input to a string vs an actual file? My conversion of input stream to string method uses a buffered reader but it gives me null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're actually talking about [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/index.html), Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org):

```
package com.stackoverflow.q2633002;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Connecting...");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://apache.cyberuse.com/httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1-bin.zip");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        try {
            System.out.println("Downloading file...");
            input = response.getEntity().getContent();
            output = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1-bin.zip");
            for (int length; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            System.out.println("File successfully downloaded!");
        } finally {
            if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
            if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
        }
    }

}
```

Works fine here. Your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: I added the content type to the header (Application/octet-stream) and using the same method, that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Open a stream and send the file:

```
try {
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream( _backupDirectory + filename );
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    int numRead;
    while ( ( numRead = is.read( buffer, 0, buffer.length ) ) != -1 ) {
        os.write( buffer, 0, numRead );
    }
    os.close();
    is.close();
}
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    System.out.println( "File " + filename + " not found" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general when you want the browser to show the download dialog box for a file to be downloaded, you should set the incoming `inputstream` content directly into the response object steam and set the content type of response (`HttpServletResponse` object) to the relevant file type.

i.e.,

```
response.setContentType(.. relevant content type)
```

Content type can be `application/pdf` for pdf files as an example.

If browser has a plugin to show relevant file in the browser window, file will open and user can save then, otherwise browser will show the download box.

Comment: Fair guess, but he's not talking about Servlet API :)

Comment: Hmmm... I think I got carried away due to httpresponse mention.. Sorry :)