# Runtime.getRuntime().exec(), how to execute file from website link?

Tags: java, runtime, execute, calc

So far I've got this line to work perfectly and it executes calc.exe on my computer:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("calc.exe");
```

But how can I download and execute a file from a website link? For example http://website.com/calc.exe

I found this code on the web but it doesn't work:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bitsadmin /transfer myjob /download /priority high http://website.com/calc.exe c:\\calc.exe &start calc.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and/or [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html), [download the file](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Download_a_file_from_a_URL_in_Java-17947.html), save it somewhere (current working directory, or a temp directory, for example), then execute it using the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.

Comment: @KarleeCorinne click on the link where it says **download the file**, it's got sample code for downloading a link and saving it as a file. Just replace the `"C:/mura-newest.zip"` with the file you want to save it as.

Comment: Yes but it looks like it contains a lot of unnecessary code. Also if I place it in the directory C:/Windows/System32/ Do I need to escape the characters by doing C://Windows///System32// ? And then for the runtime, I can just do Runtime.getRuntime().exec("file.exe"); ?

Comment: @KarleeCorinne you can skip all of the printouts and the timer, but you need everything else. You can use the current directory, as in: `new File("file.exe")` and then `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("file.exe")`

Comment: What is the current directory though?

Comment: @KarleeCorinne it is whereever you run your java program

Answer (score 0):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2633176/16959) as a starting point you could do this: (this uses [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html))

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Connecting...");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://website.com/calc.exe");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

    InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream output = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    try {
        System.out.println("Downloading file...");
        input = response.getEntity().getContent();
        output = new FileOutputStream("c:\\calc.exe");
        for (int length; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        System.out.println("File successfully downloaded!");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\calc.exe");

    } finally {
        if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    }
}
```